# What is the benefit of passing a callback to ob_start compared to just processing the result of ob_get_clean()?

Tags: php, performance, coding-style, output-buffering

I am wondering if there is any real benefit to using this...

```
function getSomeContent() {
    ob_start(function($content) {
        // ... modify content ...
        return $content;
    }
    // ... output stuff ...
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

...as opposed to this...

```
function getSomeContent() {
    ob_start();
    // ... output stuff ...
    $result = ob_get_clean();
    // ... modify content ...
    return $result;
}
```

...?

Assume the "output stuff" and "modify content" parts are the same in each case.  The key point is that the "modify content" has changed its location, being in a callback in the first case, and being "inline" in the second case.

Is there a performance benefit of one over the other?  For example, does the second form make two copies of the buffer contents when the first uses only one?  Or is it purely a coding style decision?  Why would *you* choose one form over the other?

I can see there are differences in scope access, because any variables in the enclosing scope will be available in the "modify content" part of the second example, where they would have to be "passed in" with a `use` clause in the first example.  In fact this is exactly why I would normally choose the second form.

Comment: In the first case, you don't need to do `$result = ob_get_clean();`, you'll do `ob_end_clean();` (calls the callback before cleaning too). Else the second case is yours. If you want to use the first case this way (modifying 2 times result), you'll just add complexity to your app.

Comment: Thanks @Ninsuo, but I think maybe you didn't understand my code samples properly (I wasn't clear enough in my question), so I have added a bit more context by making them into method calls with identical signatures.  The first case isn't modifying the result twice, I don't understand what you mean there, can you clarify how that is the case?  Of course I want to use `ob_get_clean()` and not `ob_end_clean()` as that simply discards the contents of the buffer, which I want to keep.  I'm asking about using the callback in `ob_start()` vs processing the result "inline" so to speak.

Comment: While I think that all of this is just a matter of coding style (with Ninsuo correctly pointing out that the callback style can get you a little cleaner code), you should re-evaluate if it is really necessary to fall back to using output buffering for capturing the output. What are you doing in between `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean`?  Wouldn't you be able to append the output to a variable in the first place?

Comment: @akirk Well to be honest, the question was mainly theoretical, and I tend to agree, however I do find it useful to wrap view scripts in `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` (without callbacks!) then the view scripts can use standard output functions (`echo` etc), and I can still manipulate the output later.  As for the callbacks, well I'm struggling to see that I would ever use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now your code is clear yes, in your first samples you given a case where you used `$result` twice (that wasn't a good idea).

My main idea is : you call `ob_start` with a callback only if you *do not* need to use your `$result` in your current scope. Your first example becomes :

```
ob_start(function($content) {
    // ... modify content ...
    return $content;
}
// ... output stuff ...
ob_end_clean();
```

In this case, the job with `$result` is made in a new scope and this can make your code cleaner (example: you call `ob_start(array($this, 'method'));`), and you don't need to `unset` your `$result` to free it from your main scope at the end of your job (I assume you're doing something else of course).

Comment: Thanks @Ninsuo.  If I understand you correctly, you are saying if you're outputting the buffer contents directly, then passing a callback to `ob_start()` can be cleaner.  But if you're doing something else with the content anyway, then there is no real benefit to using the callback.  That makes sense.  I like the idea of using a method reference as the callback, except that it grates my OO side because that method shouldn't really be public, technically it is an implementation detail that should be kept private.  (Could use `ReflectionMethod::setAccessible` perhaps).

Comment: The only thing I don't get is why you are calling `ob_end_clean()` which simply discards the buffer content.  I'm sure it's meant to be `echo ob_end_clean()` or am I missing something still?

Comment: I am using `ob_end_clean();` because when you clean the buffer, your callback is still called. So, if you're using a callback I assume you don't need your result in your main scope, so you don't need to return your `$result`. If you need to `echo ob_get_clean();`, call `ob_start` without callback. Else, use a callback. If you call `ob_start` from a class, you can use `array($this, 'method')` as callback even if `method` is private (because you call it from the same class).

Comment: "If you need to echo ob_get_clean();, call ob_start without callback."  Words of wisdom my friend, thanks.  I'm going to post an answer just for the slow ones like myself, but I'm marking yours as correct as it got me there, after I read the RTFM a few more times as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify Ninsuo's correct answer a bit.

My two code samples actually **do not** produce the same result.  In fact, using the callback in combination with `ob_get_clean()` is completely useless.

This is because the callback is applied when *cleaning* or *flushing* the buffer.

However `ob_get_clean()` retrieves the contents first, and *then* cleans the buffer.  Which means that the contents returned are not the result returned by the callback, but the input passed *to* the callback.

I wrote these two simple (and hacky) scripts to demonstrate.

This one uses `ob_get_clean()` and does not produce the correct result:

```
// Tests the use of callbacks with ob_get_clean().
class TestWithGetClean {
    // This variable is set when obcallback is called.
    public $foo = null;

    // The output buffer callback.
    public function obcallback($value) { 
        $this->foo = 'set';
        return $value . '(modified)'; 
    }

    // Main method.
    public function run() {
        ob_start(array($this, 'obcallback'));
        echo 'this is the output', PHP_EOL;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

// Run the test with ob_get_clean().
$t = new TestWithGetClean();
echo $t->run(); // This method returns a value in this test. (But not the correct value!)
echo $t->foo, PHP_EOL;
```

The output from running this is:

> this is the output
>
> set

The text `'(modified)'` does not appear anywhere.  Note however that the instance variable `$foo` *is set*, so the callback is definitely called, however the output is not as I originally expected.

Compare to this one which uses `ob_end_flush()`:

```
// Tests the use of callbacks with ob_end_flush().
class TestWithEndFlush {
    // This variable is set when obcallback is called.
    public $foo = null;
    
    // The output buffer callback.
    public function obcallback($value) { 
        $this->foo = 'set';
        return $value . '(modified)' . PHP_EOL; 
    }

    // Main method.
    public function run() {
        ob_start(array($this, 'obcallback'));
        echo 'this is the output', PHP_EOL;
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}

// Run the test with ob_end_flush().
$t2 = new TestWithEndFlush();
$t2->run(); // This method produces output in this test.
echo $t2->foo, PHP_EOL;
```

This one produces the following output:

> this is the output
>
> (modified)
>
> set

However, this is of course not as useful because the output goes directly to the client, so we cannot further manipulate the result.  (For example, wrapping the text in a Symfony HttpFoundation Component Request object).

Comment: Thanks, i was going to ask why saving the ob_get_clean returned string seems to ignore the callback function :-)